# How to get the VNC url from openstacksdk

Tags: python, openstack, vnc

As we know, the OpenStack provides the CLI to show the URL of the VNC console.

For example:

```
openstack console url show instance_name
```

Currently, I want to access the console via OpenStack Python SDK but I can't find any APIs to do it.

The question is how I can use OpenStack Python SDK to get the URL of the VNC console of an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `openstack --debug ...` you will exactly what REST API requests the tool is making. You can also check the [api reference](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/), which for recent versions of Nova suggests that you should use the [server remote consoles](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#server-remote-consoles) api (and also describes deprecated APIs available in earlier releases).

If you're using the Python SDK, a simple search of the code reveals that server objects have a [get_vnc_console](https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/blob/master/novaclient/v2/servers.py#L108) method that will do what you want.

Comment: Does libcloud or openstack connection have this kind of method to get the VNC console?